# No Result Defined for action and result

Tags: validation, jsp, servlets, struts2

I want to validate my text fields in my jsp pages. I'm using struts. My validate function throws an error as described follows.

> HTTP Status 404 - No result defined for action SIS.Student.AddUser and
>   result input

These are my form parameters.

```
<s:form id="FormAddUser" name="FormAddUser" action="AddUser" method="post"
    enctype="multipart/form-data" class="form-horizontal">
    <s:textfield key="UserId" label="UserId" />
    <s:textfield key="Name" label="Name" />
    <s:textfield key="Address" label="Address" />
    <s:textfield key="DOB" label="DOB" />
    <s:password key="Password" label="Password" />
    <s:textfield id="EmailId" key="EmailId" label="EmailId" />
    <s:textfield id="Specialization" key="Specialization" label="Specialization" />
    <s:file name="UserImage" id="UserImage" key="UserImage" label="Select a File to change photo" />
    <s:submit label="Add" />
</s:form>
```

This is my validate function inside my action class:

```
public class AddUser extends ActionSupport implements ServletRequestAware 
{

    public void validate()
   {
     if (StringUtils.isEmpty(UserId)) {addFieldError("UserId", "UserId cannot be blank");}
     if (StringUtils.isEmpty(Name)) {addFieldError("Name", "UserId cannot be blank");}
     if (StringUtils.isEmpty(Address)) {addFieldError("Address", "UserId cannot be blank");}
     if (StringUtils.isEmpty(DOB)) {addFieldError("DOB", "UserId cannot be blank");}
     if (StringUtils.isEmpty(Password)) {addFieldError("Password", "UserId cannot be blank");}
     if (StringUtils.isEmpty(EmailId)) {addFieldError("EmailId", "UserId cannot be blank");}
     if (StringUtils.isEmpty(Specialization)) {addFieldError("Specialization", "UserId cannot be blank");}
   }
```

This is my struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
<package name="studentInfo" extends="struts-default" namespace="/">
    <action name="AddUser" class="SIS.Student.AddUser"      method="execute">
        <interceptor-ref name="fileUpload">
            <param name="maximumSize">2097152</param>
            <param name="allowedTypes">
                image/png,image/gif,image/jpeg,image/pjpeg
            </param>
        </interceptor-ref>
        <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack"></interceptor-ref>

        <result name="success">/Index.jsp</result>
        <result name="error">/Index.jsp</result>
        <result name="input">/Index.jsp</result>
    </action>
</package>
```

This is the error I get:
[image]

What am I doing wrong? What should I fix?

Comment: Probably the location of the file `Index.jsp` is wrong. Check if the resource is available.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**First,**
You have given namespace="/", so you need not give the "/" in

```
<result name="success">/Index.jsp</result>
```

change it to following if you have namespace="/"

```
<result name="success">Index.jsp</result>
```

check whether this is solving your problem. check whether index.jsp has 'i' or 'I' at  0th address
**Second,**
From ur query i couldn't infer whether your program is running fine or not..
Did you test the following?
* in "Class AddUser" remove all the if conditions from validate method and place this

```
public void validate()
{
 System.out.println("in validate method");    
}
```

And in exceute method

```
public String execute()
{
 System.out.println("in execute method");    
 return SUCCESS; // assuming you are extending ActionSupport class & using default return types
}
```

- run the program, check for the output as shown below

**Expected output**
in validate method
in execute method
**DISPLAY** Index.jsp

Let me know the results if you have done this testing. if above is working, then we need to drill down for other possibilities.

**EDITED**
After validating the above scenario's, check what value you are returning from the actionMethod: execute and verify whether the returned string from action method is present in the parameters in

For example:

```
public String execute()
{
 return "hello";
}
```

and modify as follows, remove "error" and "input"

```
 <action name="AddUser" class="SIS.Student.AddUser"      method="execute">
  <!-- modified success to hello do debug with / and without /-->
  <result name="hello">index.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Comment: The first part is totally wrong. The second is not an answer at all.

Comment: why this is downvoted. give a valid reason..how do u know first part is wrong. i executed the code..first one is the answer..second is an additional info for debugging the validation, which is a proper way for proceeding

Comment: @Aleksandr  are u even familiar with the concept?? if namespace="/" and in <result> if it is given as "/index.jsp" then url would be constructed as "//index.jsp" which is not a valid url construct!!

Comment: Namespace is for actions not for the location of the results. Try it - you'll see.

Comment: /index.jsp is the result..url will be constructed as //index.jsp if namespace="/" thats y the user is getting error as result input

Comment: just remove the downvote..if u can , then provide the answers and then downvote..all that i have posted is relevant to the user's requirements and possibly issue will be resolved

Comment: Now it's even worse: `chain` type at all, `chain` for jsp, removing results.

Comment: walang salita ,,auto gen code--this is a for diagonising

Comment: @AleksandrM when u r giving downvote,first give the answer/explanation with code analysis, dont blindly say its wrong... no proper debugging results are given by the user, so i have given the possible ways for debugging..btw ur downvote doesnt matter to me..

Comment: The downvote is for the first part of your post which is incorrect. And which you haven't corrected ever since I've told you so. Read about [why voting is important](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).

Comment: @aleksandrM i disagree. just remove the downvote. and move on

Comment: So you still think that it is correct? Haven't found time to learn/try it?

Comment: am waiting to see response from user, if user disagree, then i will

Comment: @AleksandrM the person accepted the answer.. what do you say now..remove the down vote..if you find something wrong then correct it..any one can simply say its wrong..this is not a girlfirend problem which we cannot explain, programming is logical, so spot out the mistake ..no one will post just for timepassing,people need answers thats why question is posted..simply downvoting is simply just stupid